# Morphism from an open dense subscheme to a proper scheme can be extended to whole scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a proper scheme over a field $k$. $Y$ is any finite type smooth $k$-scheme and $U$ is an open dense subscheme of $Y$. Then is it true that any morphism from $U$ to $X$ can be extended from $Y$ to $X$. I know that it is true if $Y$ is curve but is it true for general schemes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This is false. Let $Y = \mathbb P^2$, and consider the rational projection map $\pi:\mathbb P^2 \dashrightarrow \mathbb P^1$ which is defined by choosing a point $p \in Y$ and a disjoint line $L \subset \mathbb Y$. For all $q \in U = Y \setminus \left\{p\right\}$, the line $\overline{pq}$ intersects $L$ in a unique point, so $\pi(q) = \overline{pq}\cap L$ gives us a map defined everywhere except $p$ and which does not extend to $p$ (one must blow up $p$ to make the map extend).

To see that the map does not extend, put $p = (0:1:0)$, so then $\pi(x:y:z) = (x:z)$. This gives a well-defined point of $\mathbb P^1$ iff $(x:y:z) \ne (0:1:0)$.

Comment: +1, of course. Another good way to see that there cannot be any possible extension to the whole of $\Bbb P^2$ is to consider approaching $p$ along a line $Z$: every point on that line must map to $Z\cap L$, so if there were a continuous extension to all of $\Bbb P^2$, by continuity $p$ must map to $Z\cap L$ as well. But you can do this for any line $Z$ through $p$.